# BIG(O) time complexity

Tags: time-complexity

What is the time Complexity for below code:

1)

```
function(values,xlist,ylist):

     sum =0 
     n=0 

    for r from 0 to xlist:
       for c from 0 to ylist:
         sum+= values[r][c]  
         n+1
    return sum/n
```

2)

```
function PrintCharacters():
    characters= {"a","b","c","d"}

  foreach character in characters
     print(character)
```

According to me the 1st code has O(xlist*ylist) complexity and 2nd code has O(n).

Is this right?

Comment: yes you are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Big O notation to describe the asymptotic behavior of functions. Basically, it tells you how fast a function grows or declines

For example, when analyzing some algorithm, one might find that the time (or the number of steps) it takes to complete a problem of size n is given by

```
T(n) = 4 n^2 - 2 n + 2
```

If we ignore constants (which makes sense because those depend on the particular hardware the program is run on) and slower growing terms, we could say "T(n)" grows at the order of n^2 " and write:T(n) = O(n^2)

For the formal definition, suppose f(x) and g(x) are two functions defined on some subset of the real numbers. We write

```
f(x) = O(g(x))
```

(or f(x) = O(g(x)) for x -> infinity to be more precise) if and only if there exist constants N and C such that

```
|f(x)| <= C|g(x)| for all x>N
```

Intuitively, this means that f does not grow faster than g

If a is some real number, we write

```
f(x) = O(g(x)) for x->a
```

if and only if there exist constants d > 0 and C such that

```
|f(x)| <= C|g(x)| for all x with |x-a| < d
```

So for your case it would be

```
O(n) as |f(x)| > C|g(x)|
```

Reference from http://web.mit.edu/16.070/www/lecture/big_o.pdf

```
 for r from 0 to xlist:  // --> n time
       for c from 0 to ylist: // n time
         sum+= values[r][c]  
         n+1

}

function PrintCharacters():
    characters= {"a","b","c","d"}
 foreach character in characters --> # This loop will run as many time as there are characters suppose n characters than it will run time so O(n)
    print(character)
```

> Big O Notation gives an assumption when value is very big outer loop
>   will run n times and inner loop is running n times
>
> Assume n -> 100 than total n^2 10000 run times

Comment: Thanks.But as per some guys in my team the 1st code has O(n) complexity and second has O(1) complexity.

Comment: explaining with example

Comment: O(n) only as when number of characters are large or n times this loop will run time